# How to record video by actionscript 3 ?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Can we record video (capture/ streaming) by actoinscript 3 ? and upload the same to server ? 
Anybody have any reference link for it ? 
your help will be appreciable 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is support for recording video and surely you can send this data to the server.

There are many tutorials available, you can find them with a simple google search:

- https://influxis.com/simple-as3-recorder/
- https://code.google.com/p/flvrecorder/ --- has a sample
- http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2012/12/record-and-play-back-video-with-air-for-ios-on-ipad/

and many, many others.

If you want to use free server, where to send video to, I suggest to look into Red5, it seems that it's not supported for a while now, but the latest releases are running well.

Red5: http://www.red5.org

Comment: Thank you for answering. Currently I am using red5 server for video streaming. But it required special dedicated server to run(if I am not wrong) and there need to connect to server while recording and customer dont want that button.There should be automatically video recording once user go to page. So trying with simple actionscript and some flash component. I will try above links. Thank you very much

Comment: Feel free to check the answer as correct if you feel satisfied with it and you believe it to be correct. It will help others with the same problem find an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

**You can capture audio and video from a webcam using Flash/ActionScript.**

The encoded audio and video data is streamed (through rtmp) from the Flash client running in a browser to a media server like Red5, Wowza and AMS where it is saved in .flv, mp4 or .f4v video files.

For the exact client AS3 code see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33697613/813988).